# Remove elements from arrayList1 which are available in arraylist2

Tags: java, arraylist

How to remove the elements of array list 1 which are avaliable from array list 2?

for example

```
ArrayList<AClass> list1 = new ArrayList<AClass>(); //AClass(int IDNumber, String date)
ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

AClass a1 = new AClass(1, "20/01/2013");
AClass a2 = new AClass(2, "21/01/2013");
AClass a3 = new AClass(3, "22/01/2013");
AClass a4 = new AClass(4, "23/01/2013");

list1.add(a1);
list1.add(a2);
list1.add(a3);
list1.add(a4);

list2.add(2);
list2.add(4);

//remove 2 and 4 from list1,
```

the size of the lists will be big, is there any methods or algorithms to remove them.

Im expecting answer as

```
// after removing Im expecting answer from list1 as
[1,22/01/2013]
[3,22/01/2013]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `HashSet<Integer>` rather than a `List<Integer>`, then iterate through `list1`, and remove every element which has a num contained in the `Set<Integer>`:

```
for (Iterator<AClass> it = list1.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    AClass c = it.next();
    if (set.contains(c.getNum())) {
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

A HashSet lookup is O(1), whereas a List lookup is O(N).

Comment: I think the OP's trying to remove elements at index 2 and 4. A HashSet won't let him do that. There are no duplicate values in his example.

Comment: No. He's trying to remove element that have, in their num field, a value that is in a second collection: *"How to remove the elements of array list 1 which are avaliable from array list 2?"*. BTW, there's no index 4 in his example.

Comment: Actually after re-reading carefully, his example doesn't make sense anyway (doesn't even compile). He uses `add(index, E item)`, which prompted my comment above, but you're right that it's possibly not what he meant.

Comment: @ARRG: its not index its an ID number, the list1 has some more column, which I didn't mention, to just show it in simple way. (1,2,3,4) are ID numbers.